# Search Product by category in magento 1.8

Tags: magento

I have to find products from category that user selected. I made a one dropdown that show all category and subcategory, now user select any category from that dropdown and search product accordingly. I am not sure what kind of changes i have to made and also which files i have to modify.So does any one know how i will achieve it. please share you idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got `category_id` from category selection

```
 $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->addAttributeToFilter("visibility",4)
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid))
    ->setOrder("position","asc");
```

Where `$catid` is your category id

In `$_productCollection` you get all product collection with specific category filter

and try to run `foreach` in `$_productCollection` to get all product infromation

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: thanks for your help. but where i have to made this changes, in which file and which function. i am new to magento.

Comment: accept the answer if you find helpful @PrashantParekh